# Override default css to make bars square

Tags: css

In this [table](https://affectionate-northcutt-5ab903.netlify.com/post/test-post/) I wish the color bars were square and not rounded.

Using Chrome > Inspect Element I see that if I change this:

```
border-radius: 0px;
padding-right: 4px;
```

I can remove the rounding of one of the bars.

1) How do I determine what to change for ALL of the bars?

I'm using Hugo and placing the css overrides into layouts > partials > head_custom.html

Thanks

Comment: Just to be very specific, give it a try: `td > span {
    border-radius: 0 !important; padding-right: 4px !important;
}`

Comment: You will need `!important` in your css file since the styles are inline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your spans have inline styling, you'll need to either change each span's styling (since normal CSS rules won't override inline styling), or you'll need to use the dreaded [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) rule:

```
td > span {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank-you. I was unaware of !important or much of css really. Now that I've crossed over to the dark side any idea why all the numbers line up except for the 70 under [Newfoundland and Labrador](https://affectionate-northcutt-5ab903.netlify.com/post/test-post/)?

Comment: Looks like that particular entry is just too narrow and it pushes the font to the left. If you try increasing it a bit it lines back up.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Increase what a bit?

Comment: The width of that particular span is set to 20.41%. If you increase it to at least 28% it then becomes wide enough for the "70" to line up properly. anything less than than pushes the text out of alignment.

Comment: Thank-you very much for your help.